# How to access instance variable in rails minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have following code of line in my controller file

```
@filters[:temp] = Job.find_all_for_referrals(@company_id, @filters[:from_time], @filters[:to_time], @filters[:temp_id])
```

When i try to access this variable in my test with **assigns(filters) or assigns(filters[:temp])** then it says

> undefined local variable or method `filters'

Is there anything that i am doing wrong or there is some other way to access filters variable in test environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assigns` expects a symbol as an argument, and you are passing it a variable `filters` that is not defined in the current scope.

This should solve your issue:

```
assigns(:filters)

assigns(:filters)[:temp]
```

Comment: Well, assigns just returns the object, so you can hash into it. See edit ^

Comment: The `assigns` now is in [rails-controller-testing](https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing) gem.